# PHP how to prevent PHP from escaping html fopen fwrite

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am trying to make an app that will allow me to more easly create HTML documents.

It mostly works except that when I write to the file it adds backslashes.

```
<a href=\"google.com\">google</a>
```

Any idea how to stop it from doing this?

I got it to work! if i stripslashes() before I write it to the file it will save/create the file with out the \ 
Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Can you post the code with your fwrite call?

Comment: fwrite($fp, stripslashes($whatever));

Comment: It adds the backslashes with and without the "stripslashes" function? Did you try echoing the $whatever string to see if there were glitches in it?

Comment: I didn't ask the question my fellow overflower, I,m merely suggesting he tries it :)

Comment: By disabling everything that has anything to do with `magic_quotes`...

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because the *magic quotes* are on, if you don't want to use the stripslashes every time, you should disable them either in your php.ini file or with an htaccess file like such:

In *php.ini* file:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

OR in *.htaccess* file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

OR disable them directly in your code:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: no access to the php.ini file (shared server) and no go on the htaccess file

Comment: No way to add an .htaccess file?? You can't even create the htaccess file where your php scripts are? I don't get why it's not possible, but if so you will have to add stripslashes every time I guess.

Comment: /me looks both ways to make sure no one is looking | I dont really understand htaccess files i added the command php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off to the end of it but it did nothing so i removed it ( dont want to mess with things i dont understand) I use it to set a 404 and that is about it

Comment: Ok. What about the php sample code to put at the beginning? Is it working with the stripslashes function? Did you also try putting the .htaccess file at the root of your website? Was the file named "htaccess" or ".htaccess"? Also make sure it doesn't have a hidden extension like windows would do, i.e. ".htaccess.txt"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single-quoted string, you shouldn't use escape double-quotes with backslashes, as they are interpreted literally.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

this behaviour is caused by PHP's deprecated [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) directive, yours is still activated, as it is by default in any  default PHP install prior to 5.4. Unless you specify a length argument, [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) will look at [magic-quotes-runtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) to see wether it'll escape or not.

to turn it off you could place

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

in a [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file, you'll need to use apache DSO to allow for this option

or you can [disable it in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

if you can't do either of these things because you're on a shared host or for another reason, then solve it in code.

```
function write($resource,$string,$length)
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $string = stripslashes($string);

    }
    return fwrite($resource, $string,$length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with a $_POST['body'] variable. This works for me:

```
str_replace("\\", "", $_POST['body']);
```

Comment: If this answers the question, please explain why. It seems like your answer addresses a different (but possibly related) problem than the one in the question.